# Google Play warns that my build "doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade"

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I'm attempting to publish a new release of my app but I get errors from the Google Play console:

```
1 Error
error
Error
You can't rollout this release because it doesn't allow any existing users to upgrade to the newly added APKs.

4 Warnings
1 MESSAGE FOR VERSION CODE 4004
Warning
None the of users of this APK will be able to upgrade to any of the new APKs added in this release.

1 MESSAGE FOR VERSION CODE 2004
Warning
None the of users of this APK will be able to upgrade to any of the new APKs added in this release.

1 MESSAGE FOR VERSION CODE 1004
Warning
None the of users of this APK will be able to upgrade to any of the new APKs added in this release.

1 MESSAGE FOR VERSION CODE 5
Warning
This App Bundle contains native code, and you've not uploaded debug symbols. We recommend you upload a symbol file to make your crashes and ANRs easier to analyze and debug. Learn More
```

Any clue what might be going wrong?

Comment: I didn't want to completely re-write this question, but I tried because I was facing this as well and this was one of *FOUR* results (which led me to realize the issue).

If OP had included screen shots of their build information it would have revealed that their versions were out of whack.  The error is incredibly opaque, but the answer in this thread is correct.

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, your android-versionCode from your current build is lower than the version already available on your Google Play Store.

Change the android-versionCode of your APP to a number HIGHER than the version already available and it will work.!

Comment: In my case, the switch from using APK to AAB actually *decreased* the versionCode for one of the architectures (x86_64), triggering this message.  I had to increase my versionCode to 2000000 to compensate as the generated version codes are in the millions though my versionCode in build.gradle was <100.

Comment: What Freewalker suggested worked for me.  My versionCode was always higher, but for some reason it needed to be MUCH higher this time.

Comment: Thats really weird 